# Is it correct to use "hardest" here? If yes, can you please explain it?

Tags: grammar

I found the following sentence on [writing.utoronto.ca/advice](http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/english-as-a-second-language/articles):

> I need to study **hardest** for the exam that I write next Wednesday

Is it correct to use hardest here? If yes, can you please explain it?

I haven't used *hardest* before.

Answer (score 1):

*I need to study hardest for the exam that I write next Wednesday.*

*... the hardest ...* is unnatural if you are comparing your intensity of work for Wednesday's exam with your level of work for something else. It is possible if your are comparing your intensity of work with somebody else's.

*I need to study hard for the exams that I write on Monday and Tuesday, but I need to study **hardest** for the exam that I write next Wednesday.*

*Luke and Emma need to study hard for the examination we write next Wednesday, but I need to study **the hardest**.*

.

Michael Swan, (*Practical English Usage*, 2004.142) gives these examples:

> *She works (the) hardest in her family; her husband doesn't know what work is.* (A woman is being compared with the man - *the* is possible.
>
> *She works hardest when she is doing something for her family.* (NOT (*)*She works the hardest when ...*; a woman's work is being compared
>   in different situations.)
>
> The is sometimes dropped before superlative adverbs in an informal
>   style. 
>   *Who can run (the) fastest.*

Note that in British English we usually *take* or (more formally) *sit* an exam.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct and sounds natural when spoken. It's common to say things like  "I will study hard" or "I have been studying hard." So it simply means that Wednesday's exam will require the most studying/effort.

Another example of using "hardest" this way is, "I work hardest on projects that I care about."

Answer (score 0):

I need to study the hardest for the exam that I write next Wednesday.

I think this would be a more correct sentence